# Sorting 2d string array with integer

Tags: java, sorting

i created a 2d string array (called data) which contains on the first position an integer (as a string) and on the second position a link to a file.

Examples:

```
["3", "Test3.pdf"]; ["1", "Test1.pdf"];  ["2", "Test2.pdf"];  ["10", "Test10.pdf"]
```

So now I need to sort the array ascending for the integer. So the result of the sorting should be an sorted array like:

```
["1", "Test1.pdf"];  ["2", "Test2.pdf"];["3", "Test3.pdf"];["10", "Test10.pdf"]
```

I found some sample code for this:

```
Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
        final String time1 = entry1[0];
        final String time2 = entry2[0];
        return time1.compareTo(time2);
    }
});
```

but the problem is, that in this case it compares it with string logic, so the result would be-> 1,10,2,3. So I cannot archive the result with this. Do you know what can I do? You only can have an 2d array of one type? not mix of string and integer?

Comment: Do you *need* to have this as an array of arrays of strings? A simple collection of objects with separate `int` and `String` parts would almost certainly be better, not just here but throughout your code.

Comment: If you need to have strings in the array, just convert to `int` in the `compare` method.

Comment: The best structure to handle your problem is `TreeMap<Integer,String>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison can be done by converting the first element to Integer, as demonstrated in the following snippet:

```
Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
        final Integer time1 = Integer.valueOf(entry1[0]);
        final Integer time2 = Integer.valueOf(entry2[0]);
        return time1.compareTo(time2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
    Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
        final Integer time1 = Integer.parseInt(entry1[0]);
        final Integer time2 = Integer.parseInt(entry2[0]);
        return time1.compareTo(time2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this answer any different from the one posted 8 minutes earlier?

Comment: basically not..i just didn't see it while I was testing it